Is there a way to achieve sticky header tabs behavior such as TikTok/X/Instagram profile in SwiftUI?
I want to achieve sticky header tab view behavior such as TikTok, X and Instagram profile screens have. I have found tutorial solving similar problem. However, the issue is that whenever we scroll, the same scroll offset applies to all tabs, but I want each of tabs to have its separate scroll offset. How to achieve that behavior using SwiftUI and iOS 15 ?
You can observe this small example:
enum Page {
    case first, second, third
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var page: Page = .first
    
    var numbers: [Int] = (0..<1000).map { $0 }
    
    let letters = (0..<125).map { i -> String in
        let asciiValue = 97 + (i % 26)
        return String(UnicodeScalar(asciiValue)!)
    }
    
    let combinedArray = (0..<123).map { i -> String in
        let numberPart = i + 1
        let asciiValue = 97 + (i % 26)
        let letterPart = String(UnicodeScalar(asciiValue)!)
        return "\(numberPart)\(letterPart)"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .center, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                
                Text("Header to be hidden")
                Text("Header to be hidden")
                Text("Header to be hidden")
                Text("Header to be hidden")
                Text("Header to be hidden")
                
                Section(content: {
                    Content()
                }, header: {
                    StickyHeader()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func StickyHeader() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button("First") {
                page = .first
            }
            Button("Second") {
                page = .second
            }
            Button("Third") {
                page = .third
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .background(Color.pink)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func Content() -> some View {
        switch page {
        case .first:
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(numbers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(numbers[index].description).id(index)
                }
            }
        case .second:
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(letters.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(letters[index]).id(index)
                }
            }
        case .third:
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(combinedArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(combinedArray[index]).id(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I have found a package, this completely works fine, however, there is only support from iOS 17.
Find demo video for wanted behavior

Hey @AlisaMartirosyan, did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same question

Hi @RomanMahotskyi, unfortunately no
